# How to Create NSDictionary with Multi Level

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Can you help me how to create NSDictionary format of the following structure.

```
  Children =     (
            {
        Children =             (
                            {
                Children =                     (
                                            {
                        Children =                             (
                            Monty,
                            Smithers,
                            Frink,
                            Carl,
                            Cletus,
                            Bobo,
                            Duff
                        );
                        Name = Simpsons;
                    },
                                            {
                        Children =                             (
                            "Mountain Unicycling",
                            "Rock Climbing",
                            Bouldering,
                            Snowboarding
                        );
                        Name = Sports;
                    },
                                            {
                        Children =                             (
                            "Eating Strawberries",
                            Mangoes,
                            Treehouses,
                            "Good Weather",
                            Maui,
                            Trogdor
                        );
                        Name = "Just Fun Stuff";
                    },
                    "Foo with the Bar",
                    Bar,
                    BooFar,
                    "Foo Bar"
                );
                Name = Shows;
            },
                            {
                Children =                     (
                                            {
                        Children =                             (
                            "Big Sur",
                            "New York",
                            Naples,
                            "Chez Panisse",
                            Lucia,
                            Switzerland,
                            Ireland
                        );
                        Name = Vacation;
                    },
                                            {
                        Children =                             (
                            "Green Bay",
                            Milwaukee,
                            Monroe
                        );
                        Name = Other;
                    }
                );
                Name = Travel;
            },
                            {
                Children =                     (
                    Kark,
                    Valen,
                    Kosh,
                    "Red Letter",
                    "Fluffy Ears",
                    Hiro
                );
                Name = "Science Fiction";
            }
        );
        Name = "Favorite Things Group";
    },
            {
        Children =             (
            Mischief,
            Mayhem,
            Soap
        );
        Name = "Movies Group with a Long Title";
    },
            {
        Children =             (
            ObjC,
            Cocoa,
            KVC,
            NSTooblar
        );
        Name = "Things That Rule";
    },
            {
        Name = Eagle;
    }
  );
  Name = OVRoot;
}
```

I have to tried many ways. Still i struggle with the NSDictionary code. This is my code is following.

```
  NSArray *desk = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Desktop",@"Mac App",@"IOS App"];
 NSMutableDictionary *secondtype = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Desktop",@"Name",
                                [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:desk],@"Children",nil];


 NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"OVRoot",@"Name",
                                [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:secondtype,
                                nil], @"Children",nil];
```

Could you pls help me to how to create this hierarchy as dynamically. In my project scope is  display the Desktop, document all folder name in tree format.

Comment: This is as simple as creating a dictionary with an object or array where each of the object again stores a dictionary....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Tander mentioned I wouldn't use here a NSDictionary (eventhough it possible...).

Try to create a new data-type for your needs rather than compromise the dictionary. 
something like:

```
@interface MyFolder
    @property(nonatomic) NSString* folderName;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray* subFolders;

    //more relevant members/actions here... 

@end
```

you may also create a static factory method to deserialize a string into 'MyFolder' instance (which will be recursive of course..)

Good  Luck

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary is for key-value PAIRS only. Its not meant to act like a database and abused in the way you're trying to do so. Have you considered using another type of data structor for this?

Comment: Actually Here i shows the list of folder name in my application. Is I did tree format. and i got the list of folder name from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, then how can i shows.